# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in thread

Tags: android

In my app the java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError occurs some times is there any solution for this I cant fix this.

Code:

```
        int nvail = 0;
        try {
            nvail = new APICALL(ctx).execute(Modules.serverCheckLink).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my APICALL class: (EDITED)

```
public class APICALL extends AsyncTask<String, Long, Integer> {
private ProgressDialog loading;
Context context;

public APICALL(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, null, "Please wait..");
    super.onPreExecute();
}

protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    if (loading != null && loading.isShowing()) {
        loading.dismiss();
    }
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    Activity act = (Activity) context;
    NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager) act
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null || !info.isConnected())
        return 0;
    else {
        try {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0].replaceAll(" ",
                    "%20"));

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 5000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;
            HttpConnectionParams
                    .setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                    httpParameters);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String Response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            if (Response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Log:

```
 06-05 12:47:20.986: W/dalvikvm(2055): Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown while initializing Landroid/os/AsyncTask;
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/dalvikvm(2055): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401ca760)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at palmagent.NorthShoreAgent.Two.Modules.checkSavedNetsheet(Modules.java:2338)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at palmagent.NorthShoreAgent.Two.Modules.getData(Modules.java:2174)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at palmagent.NorthShoreAgent.Two.Modules.CheckingExpiry(Modules.java:2802)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at palmagent.NorthShoreAgent.Two.Pass.DoWork(Pass.java:434)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at palmagent.NorthShoreAgent.Two.Pass.access$1(Pass.java:391)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at palmagent.NorthShoreAgent.Two.Pass$DoinTask.run(Pass.java:372)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:595)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:595)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:184)
06-05 12:47:20.986: W/System.err(2055):     ... 6 more
```

Comment: Are you instantiating the `AsyncTask` from the main `thread`? See the docs for the `AsyncTask` constructor here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#AsyncTask()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Looper.prepare();
nvail = new APICALL(ctx).execute(Modules.serverCheckLink).get();
Looper.loop()
```

Comment: I tried but it keeps on loading I have attached me APICALL class. Is there any thing wrong in it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the first code snippet where you call execute, ie

```
new APICALL(ctx).execute(...
```

That code snippet must be performed on the main thread not a background thread. Use a handler if necessary

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

void myFunc() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            nvail = new APICALL(ctx).execute(Modules.serverCheckLink).get();
        }
    });
}
```